# How to map HashMap keys to a select in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a HashMap which looks pretty much like this..

```
class MyDTO
{
private Map<Long, StringListWrapper> myMap=new HashMap<>();
private List<Long> keys=new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> values=new ArrayList<>();
// setter and getter methods
}
class StringListWrapper
{
private List<String> st=new ArrayList<>();
// setter and getter methods
}
```

Now, for the map keys, I have a select which will contain the keys, and a list box which will be used for values.

```
<select th:field="*{myMap}">
<option th:each="key : *{keys} th:value="${key}" th:text="${key}"></option>
</select>
```

Here above, `keys` refer to the `keys` in `MyDTO`. I used it to show the keys in the `<select>`. However, this select must be mapped to the `myMap` to make sure that the option selected here acts as a key.

```
<select multiple="multiple">
<option th:each="value : *{values}" th:value="${value}" th:text="${value}"></option>
</select>
```

Now, also this above multiple select must be mapped to `myMap` so that the options selected here get into the `StringListWrapper.st`. Now, how and where to put the `th:field` attribute for multiple select above?

Thanks in advance. Hope you will reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things unclear about the question, but based on the code, I'm assuming that the `myMap` property is a `Map` because you will be providing multiple pairs of these select fields for uses to select the values for some number of keys.

If the assumption above is false, then why have `myMap` as a `Map` instead of two different properties/attributes of `MyDTO`?

Going with my assumption, you'll need the select pairs to be converted into a `List` or array in `MyDTO` and have a getter (`getMyMap()`) that creates a `Map` based of the list.  The entry in the list above would be a simple value object with `Long key` and `List<String>` as its properties.  Here is an working example of this use case.  See how this is transformed by Thymeleaf and you might find a tweaked version that works with your solution.

Also, minor thing:  IMHO, I don't believe it's appropriate to have the `keys` and `values` properties be within `MyDTO`, though it might just be simplified for this question only.  They should be model attributes instead since they are not user inputs of the form.  It technically works but doesn't strictly adhere to separation of concerns.

References/Credits:  Dynamic Form Fields - http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields

Spring Controller:

```
package net.martian111.examples.spring.web;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/public/stackoverflow/q26181188")
public class StackoverflowQ26181188Controller {

    public static class Entry {
        private Long id;

        private List<String> values;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public List<String> getValues() {
            return values;
        }

        public void setValues(List<String> values) {
            this.values = values;
        }

    }

    public static class FormBackingBean {
        List<Entry> entries;

        public List<Entry> getEntries() {
            return entries;
        }

        public void setEntries(List<Entry> entries) {
            this.entries = entries;
        }

        public Map<Long, List<String>> getMyMap() {
            Map<Long, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (Entry entry : entries) {
                // StringListWrapper constructed from entry.getValues() here...
                map.put(entry.getId(), entry.getValues());
            }
            return map;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 1;
            for (Entry entry : entries) {
                sb.append("Pair #" + i + ": ID=" + entry.getId() + ", Values="
                        + entry.getValues() + "\n");
                ++i;
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    // Can be set within the @RequestMapping methods too (mv.addObject())
    @ModelAttribute("keys")
    public List<Long> getKeys() {
        return Arrays.asList(null, 1L, 2L, 3L);
    }

    @ModelAttribute("values")
    public List<String> getValues() {
        return Arrays.asList(null, "abc", "def", "ghi");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView get() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("stackoverflow/q26181188");
        // Blank Form Backing Bean
        FormBackingBean fbb = new FormBackingBean();
        fbb.setEntries(Arrays.asList(new Entry(), new Entry(), new Entry(),
                new Entry(), new Entry()));
        mv.addObject("fbb", fbb);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView post(FormBackingBean fbb) {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("stackoverflow/q26181188");
        mv.addObject("fbb", fbb);

        // Print Form Backing Bean
        System.out.println("FBB: \n" + fbb);

        // Redisplay submitted from
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf Template:

```
    <div th:each="entry,entryStat : *{entries}">
      Pair #<span th:text="${entryStat.count}">1</span>
      <select th:field="*{entries[__${entryStat.index}__].id}">
        <option th:each="key : ${keys}" th:value="${key}" th:text="${key}"></option>
      </select>
      <select multiple="multiple" th:field="*{entries[__${entryStat.index}__].values}">
        <option th:each="value : ${values}" th:value="${value}" th:text="${value}"></option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:  Additional details in response to the first comment**
Both `Map` and `List` properties can be mapped to a collection of HTML form fields.  Each `Map.Entry` or list element is mapped to a single HTML form field, with the name in the form `propertyName[index]`, where index is the integer index of the element for the case of a `List`, or is the key value of the entry for the case of a `Map`.  The solution above illustrates this for the `List` case.

To illustrate the `Map` case, say you want an HTML form to result in a `myMap` with the following contents:

```
123L : ["abc", "def"]
234L : ["abc", "ghi"]
```

Working backwards, the query string (before URL encoding) required for Spring MVC to create the `Map` above will need to look like:  `myMap[123]=abc&myMap[123]=def&myMap[234]=abc&myMap[234]=ghi`.  To get a **browser** to submit that query string, the HTML form will have to have two multi `<select>` form elements, one with `name="myMap[123]"` and the other with `name="myMap[234]"`.  However, the name of form elements cannot be set by another form field in *standard HTML*.  In other words, there is no `th:field` value for the key `<select>` elements to do this (answering this Stackoverflow question).

With that said, an outside-the-box solution would be client side JavaScript scripting that gathers the necessary data from the form fields and create the required query string to submit the form.  It would be a SO different question for a different audience, but I feel that would be an unnecessarily complex and specialized.  Also, whereas the solution above works both to generate the HTML view from `MyDTO` and back to `MyDTO` from a form submission using the **same** HTML form, a JavaScript solution will require distinct specialized code for each direction.

Comment: Thank you. Here, you have provided an alternative way for using the map by creating a new class called `Entity` which contains the `id` (which is analogous to key of `myMap` and the `List<String>` is the value. This is OK. But, isn't there any way without modifying the architecture?

Comment: I've added more details to the end of my original question.  Short answer is "No" given the parameters of the original StackOverflow question.  Out-of-scope solutions may include things like client-side JavaScript.  However, I don't see why this would be necessary.  If `MyDTO` is a model object used throughout your application for other purposes, then `MyDTO` should probably not be used as the form-backing bean for this form.  The form-backing bean between a view and a controller exists for a specific purpose, and should not affect the architecture for the rest of the application.